# SRID for basic X,Y coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, srid

I would like to build a web-based application using leaflet which will have a flat plane and a simple X,Y coordinate system. Is there an SRID I can use for this? I will be generating my own basemaps based on the coordinates.

If it helps you conceptualize what I am doing just consider the game Zork where you move in an X,Y grid. It is similar except I would like to use Leaflet to create this to allow the user to pan, zoom and load basemaps for the different Z-Indexes.

Comment: Just use WGS84 which is SRID 4326. Leaflet translates this well.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for theoretical space, use a projected coordinate system (PCS) Any will work - UTM, pick a zone.

I don't recommend using a geographic coordinate system (GCS) as these are spherical projections and you need a flat projection - so don't use WGS84.

Here's some info about projections http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/89b720a5-7339-44b0-8b58-0f5bf2843393.htm#ProjectedCoordSys.

You can also create your own projected coordinate system https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008500